# Applying for eVisitor visa after WHV

Tags: visas, australia, working-holiday

Long story short.. I got back to England about 2 months ago after a 1 year working holiday visa in Australia. I was planning on doing a 2nd year but when I was 8 weeks into my regional work I found out my mum had cancer and had to come home. This meant I was 5 weeks short for my 2nd year visa. Some of my other friends also ran out of time because they struggled to find work, so they were short too, but they applied for their 2nd year anyway and it was granted to them with no questions asked. Apparently 1 in 7 people get their applications investigated to make sure they really did the work.

I want to go back to Australia in february to do the things I didn't get a chance to do in my 1st year, so I stupidly decided to try and apply for a 2nd year as well and I happened to be the one that got asked to send evidence. All the evidence I have will show that I only worked for 8 weeks, so if I send it the application will be rejected and it will be down on record that I was denied a visa and I will be barred from Australia for 3 years.

Now I am thinking the best thing to do would be to withdraw the application myself before it gets denied. My question is, if i withdraw the application, does anybody know if this will have any effect on an application for an eVisitor or ETA visa?

I plan to work for the next few months and save up as much as I can so that I can take a bank statement of my funds with me to show at the airport to prove I can support myself without working. I will be going with my boyfriend whose aunt lives in Perth and we can stay with her for free whilst we are there so I wont need money for accommodation.  What do you think my chances of being granted an eVisitor or ETA visa are after I withdraw my 2nd WHV application?

Answer (score 3):

If the Working Holiday application has already been submitted (and the fee has been collected) and you believe the application will be refused,  you can withdraw it if a decision has not been reached.

Applying for a visitor visa shortly afterwards is perilous.  Serial applications often suggest a secondary agenda which is unrelated to tourism or business.  Based upon what you wrote, your agenda would be to maintain a relationship with your bf and stay the whole time in Perth.  Is it really tourism?  To make matters worse, you did not comply with the terms of your WHV in your previous stay.

So to answer your question: '*what do you think my changes of being granted...*', I think they are poor.  Your application would need supporting evidence to show your solvency and readiness to return to England in order to be successful.